# XPath wild card

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an xml which is something like

```
<A>
   <B>
      <C1>
          <D> some text 1 </D>
      </C1>
      <C2>
          <D> some text 2 </D>
      </C2>
   </B>
</A>
```

I want to use a wildcard to get the text of all D element nodes. I tried /A/B/*/D/text() but it doesnt seem to work. Help appreciated.

Comment: What about //D  ? This should give what you are looking for.

Comment: Your XPath `/A/B*/D/text()` is correct and will give you the expected result. Probably there is something going wrong the way you execute the query. It also is significantly faster than `//D` as this will look at all nodes in this tree, which can be a lot (which of course depends on your input data)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `//` oprator. It will give you all the `D` elements in the document.

```
//D/text()
```